# Adjust the size of a container view's View Controller programatically in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller, container-view

I've set up a container view for some Container View controller   programatically like this

```
var containerView : UIView!
var controller :    UIViewController!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    containerView = UIView()
    containerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0 , y: 200 , width: 375, height: 400)
    self.view.addSubview(containerView)


    controller = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "containerVC")
    addChildViewController(controller)
    controller.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
    containerView.addSubview(controller.view)

}
```

In the storyboard I give the container View Controller a custom size by selecting the Container *View Controller -> Utilities -> Size Inspector* -> Selecting *Freeform* in the view tab and giving it a custom size.

[image]

The problem is that the containerVC's view doesn't fit inside the   container view since it will always have a default size of (375 , 667).

[image]

How do I change the size of the Container View Controller so that it has the specified size?

Comment: Why aren't you using constraints?

Comment: I'm just trying to get the simplest version to work and the issue wasn't with constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget to give frame size for containerVC's view. Do it just after you add it to superview.